# How to pass Azure ARM template object value from YAML file?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-resource-manager

Azure ARM Template parameter.json file has the below object property.

```
  "appInsightsObject": {
        "value": {
            "name": "appInsghtName",
            "id": "appInsgID"
        }
    }
```

I have to replace these values from build.yaml file. My build.yaml file has the below

```
  - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
    displayName: APIM Development CI
    inputs:
      ConnectedServiceName: My-Service-Name
      subscriptionName: My-Subs-Values
      resourceGroupName: My-Rg-Name
      location:$(locationName)
      csmFile: template.json
      csmParametersFile: parameters.json
      overrideParameters: '-appInsightsObject.name $(appInsightNameValue) '
```

How to pass appInsightsObject object value?

**Update:**

I found one way of passing the value as JSON object like '{"name":"name-goes-here", "id":"id-value-goes-here"}'. Is there any better option?

overrideParameters: '-appInsightsObject $(appInsightValue) '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one works and allows to store values individually for any type of object.

```
overrideParameters: '-appInsightsObject {"name": "$(dev.insightName)","id": "$(dev.insightId)"} '
```